# Why does browser block popup windows in callback but not otherwise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Strange behavior - Im trying to open a new window in a callback - using Angular but probably a general JS issue.

If I do this:

```
$window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
```

It works fine. However this doesn't as it gets blocked by my browser - I am using Safari 7 and have "block popup windows" checked:

```
Items.list(function(items) {
  $window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')
});
```

Why does the browser block that and not the other and how can I circumvent this? I played with setTimeout as well as some SO post suggestion to assign $window.open to a variable before calling async but did not work here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Popup blocker logic often blocks popup windows when the popup window is not opened as a direct consequence of a user action (like a click).

A callback that happens asynchronously is NOT a direct consequence of a user action - it's sometime later and is not directly connected to that action (as the browser sees it), thus the browser may not allow it.

The usual work-around is to open the popup window immediately (as a direct consequence of the user action) and then populate its content later after the asynchronous callback occurs and the content is available.

Comment: Great that worked. I opened a blank window with `var wnd = $window.open("", "_blank");` then wrote a string to it in my callback (generating a pdf in my case) with `wnd.document.location.href = string;`

Answer (score 1):

Does angular 6 support popup window like javascript? I am not looking for a modal window solution. I want to be able move the window to another screen like you can do with JavaScript popup windows. Is there any documentation on that? How can you go about doing it on Angular 5/6 ie to open a pop up window